# Removing duplicated rows from from matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

I have a matrix that is similar to

```
 2013  1  0    
 2013  1  30
 2013  1  100
 2013  2  0
 2013  2  30
 2013  2  100
 2013  3  0
 2013  3  30
 2013  3  100
 2013  1  0
 2013  1  30
 2013  4  0
```

Where there are extra columns after the third that have extra data.
I need a way to remove the duplicate rows.  In this example I would need to remove the rows that had a 1 in the second column.  Is there a way to remove these rows while maintaining the rest of my data.

I have tried unique() and duplicate() and could not produce what I need.  if I matrix was m.dat I tried using

```
m.dat <- m.dat[-duplicated(m.dat[,2:3])]
```

but that doesn't work. Am I using duplicate wrong or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
m.dat<-m.dat[m.dat[ ,2]!=1, ]
```

or

```
m.dat<-m.dat[!(m.dat[ ,2]==1 & duplicated(m.dat[,1:3]) , ]
```

depending on what you're looking for. I am somewhat confused if you want to remove just records with value '1' in the second column or those with '1' and which are also duplicate rows

if you wanted to know what numbers are repeated in that column you could use something like

```
reps<-unique(m.dat[,2][duplicated(m.dat[,2])])
```

and then remove all of these with a %in% statement

something like...

```
m.dat<-m.dat[ ! m.dat[,2] %in% unique(m.dat[,2][duplicated(m.dat[,2])]) ,]
```

Comment: In the second column that pattern continues all the way to 365. In my actual matrix I whave 48 1's then 48 2's then 48 3's and so on all the way to 365.  At some points in the column I have a number being repeated. For example I may have 48 5's then I will have 12 1's again.  In this case, I need to remove all rows that contain the number 1. Both the original 48 plus any that show up later on in the column.

Comment: the top code will remove any rows in which column 2 has value 1. Sounds like that is what you are looking for

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for.  Instead of using 1 is there something more generic?  Not necessarily for 1 but for any repeated number?

Comment: I edited the response above, I think we may be getting closer to what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  What I used was

```
 m <- duplicated(m.dat[,3:4])
 m <- as.numeric(m)
 ind = which(m ==1)
 m.dat = m.dat[-ind,]
```